# Python script for Web scraping

Tags: python, pandas, http, python-requests

I wrote a Python script for Web scraping of a Website. Please review my code and suggest me any changes or make me aware of my blunders/mistakes?.
I wrote the almost same script for other websites also so please can you suggest me a way to combine all other scripts into one script so that I can get one single [merged] file.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

def geturl():
  urls = [
               # List of URLs

           ]
  main = [] 
  id = 0 
  for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(r.content)
    print(r.status_code)
    items = data['items']  
    baseurl = #URL   
    for item in items:
      data = {}
      data['id']= id
      data['Title'] = item['name']
      data["Price"] = item['price']
      data['Detai Page'] =baseurl+item['slug']
      data['Image'] = item['thumb_image']
      id += 1
      main.append(data)
  sr= pd.Series(main)
  sr.to_json('data.json', orient='records')
  


geturl()
```

Comment: Are you able to share any real URLs, or at least markup from the real pages?

Comment: This has nothing to do with functional programming, web scraping or BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 2):

- When using *Requests* to fetch JSON content, it's usually more convenient to use the `resonse.json()` method instead of manually passing `response.content` to `json.loads`.
- As far as I can tell, you're using *Pandas* to turn a dictionary into a JSON string and write it to a file - as far as I can tell, the structure doesn't change. That seems to me like a strange reason to use *Pandas*. It seems to me like you could get the same results in a simpler way by doing something like

  ```py
  with open("data.json", "w") as output_file:
      json.dump(main, output_file)
  ```
- That said, I somewhat dislike not having the ability to just fetch the data without also writing it to a file. Personally I'd have a separate function to fetch the data, which could in turn be called by the larger `geturl` function.
- Hard-coding URLs and output paths makes your function less reusable than it could be. Consider having it take such things as parameters instead.
- Right now, the last line of your script calls `geturl` not just whenever the script itself is run, but also whenever this file is imported as part of a larger program. That's awkward, since I'm sure this function might be useful elsewhere too. You can avoid having the code run when imported by putting it in an `if __name__ == '__main__'` block.
- Creating `data` as an empty `dict` and adding elements one by one is a fine approach. However, for `dict`s like this one, which are small, and have consistent structures and simple contents, I often find it neater to just make it all at once with a single `dict` literal. But that's a matter of taste, and your current approach works just fine.
- Re-using the name of a built-in function (such as `id`) for another variable will work, but is generally not considered great practice - I'd suggest renaming the `id` variable for that reason.

Put that all together, you might end up with something like:

```py
import requests
import json


def get_item_data(urls, detail_base_url):
    main = []
    item_id = 0
    for url in urls:
        r = requests.get(url)
        data = r.json()
        for item in data['items']:
            item_data = {
                'id': item_id
                'Title': item['name']
                'Price': item['price']
                'Detai Page': detail_base_url + item['slug']
                'Image': item['thumb_image']
            }
            id += 1
            main.append(item_data)
    return main

def save_item_data(urls, detail_base_url, output_filename):
    item_data = get_item_data(urls, detail_base_url)
    with open(output_filename, 'w') as output_file:
        json.dump(item_data, output_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # TODO: We might want to get these from the command line. The "argparse" module would be useful for that
    urls = [ ... ]
    detail_base_url = ...
    output_file_name = 'data.json'

    save_item_data(urls, detail_base_url, output_file_name)
```

Answer (score -3):

When you work with requests and json transformations you should allways wrap that code on a try except block

```
r = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(r.content)
print(r.status_code)
```

Should be rewrite to

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.ok:
        data = response.json()
except (requests.exceptions.RequestException, json.decoder.JSONDecodeError) as exc:
    print(exc)
```

Those are the minimal changes that you need to do when you work with APIs and use json transformations and requests library.

Hope it helps

Comment: This is... not right. Universally catching and printing exceptions is the opposite of good practice.